# AngularJS: Difference between Template and View?

Tags: angularjs

I know it might be an easy question, but I didn't find an answer :-/

I read in SPA many times the word '*Templates*' into which the data is loaded. Are '*Templates*' just a regular View into which the data is filled into? Or what is the difference and do they overlap?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "view" but templates in angular mean "html code with angular directives".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A template is just an HTML file that has angular commands written in it.

It presumes you will be using angular directives/controllers to switch content instead of statically serving different HTML pages each distinct from each other: a single page application! One html page versus 10+ for a website.

The view is just a definition of purpose/responsibilites/tasks which varies depending on MVC framework chosen. Its not actually a file you write code called " view".

Comment: Thx, made it little bit more clear. But what's the mysterious reg. SPA? I mean you have many templates - so what's the `single` page in it?

Comment: The template index.HTML.....it loads all HTML Dom elements based on URL or directives. So your overall project will likely has JavaScript and tiny HTML files loaded dynamically as needed.

Answer (score 5):

- A template in angularJs is a HTML with additional markup in it, You can read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#template, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/
- A view is according to angularJs documentation is the parsed and processed template (the DOM)

> When AngularJS starts your application, it parses and processes this new markup from the template using the compiler. The loaded, transformed and rendered DOM is then called the view.

ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#view